# Pass JSON Object through Jquery GET call to Java Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

how can i pass a JSON Array/Object with the JQUERY get Method to my Java Servlet?

So far , here's my code:

```
 var json = {
        MA_ID : $("#emplID").val(),
        MA_Nachname : $("#nachname").val()
 }
  $.get(url + "/MA_Update", json) 
  [...]
```

MA_Update.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        jb.append(line);
    }

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // crash and burn
        throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
    }
}
```

But I only get

```
{"Request-URI":"","Method":"","HTTP-Version":""}
```

from my request

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `request.getReader()`, use `request.getParameter("MA_ID")` etc., or `request.getParameterMap()` (and iterate over it).

The thing is, that `$.get(url, jsObject)` creates a HTTP GET request, where the fields of the jsObject are transformed into query parameters, i.e. `http://your.server.com/MA_Update?MA_ID=someID&MA_Nachname=SomeLastName`, so they are NOT available in the request body (as they would be in a POST request).